# What are the possible reasons for (extremely) slow data ingestion into my local table via linked server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, linked-server

I’m trying to download data for analysis in my local SQL server via the following query:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.my_table
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (linked_server, ‘SELECT * FROM remote_table’)
```

- The remote_table and my_table structures are identical.
- There are a lot of nulls in the data.
- remote_table has 50 million records.
- No filters applied
- I use a SQL Server with the table being queried residing on an Oracle database.

The data download is taking forever and I’m surprised by this. Similar queries on the same schema / DB for tables with c. 10 million records took about 10 minutes tops. However I’m having no luck with remote_table despite the query running for 2 hours!

Can anyone please suggest some possible reasons for the slow performance and what I can do to speed things up?

Thanks!

Comment: Because **50 million records** - and perhaps a slower network or blocking in the source

Comment: What if you do use filters and don't do everything at once? Can something be blocking your query? What if you only select and don't insert? What if you just do count(*)? There's so many things you could have tried...

Comment: Thank you. I have tried some of these suggestions already. The count(*) returns the figure of 50mil in a couple of seconds. While just the select starts returning data straight away, it’s not good enough as I need a copy of the data locally. I can’t see anything blocking my query either!

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you are using a large Fetch_Size in your Oracle connection, and if that doesn't fix it, test in SqlDeveloper or similar.  See eg

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver N'MyOracle', 'Oracle', 'ORAOLEDB.Oracle', N'//172.16.8.119/xe', N'FetchSize=2000', ''
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dbrowne/creating-a-linked-server-for-oracle-in-64bit-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

I would find out if this runs:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.my_table
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (linked_server, ‘SELECT TOP 100 * FROM remote_table’)
```

50 million is a lot of records, so it will take a long time no matter what you do.  Is there no way to filter them or remove any fields that are BLOBs?